# illegal harware instruction when trying to run flask application

Tags: python, macos, zsh, cpu-architecture, apple-m1

First of all here is my mac info:

```
macOS Big Sur
Apple M1 Chip
16 GB memory
Python 3.7.9
```

I tried to run a python application in my computer. After I input `flask run`, the terminal returns

```
 * Serving Flask app "demo" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with fsevents reloader
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 260-335-544
I0806 10:14:55.217031 12914655232 file_utils.py:40] PyTorch version 1.6.0 available.
I0806 10:14:55.217122 13005393920 file_utils.py:40] PyTorch version 1.6.0 available.
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  flask run
```

Does anyone know what that mean and how to solve it? (Pretty sure there is no bug in the code. And I installed all the required packages)

Comment: Hey @ti7. I actually found this blog before. I guess it is more about tensorflow than flask. Although there are some good reference, the blog post didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Nothing to do with `zsh` itself, that's just the shell reporting that your process ended with SIGILL.  It's actually an AVX issue.

Comment: Got it. Is there a way to get rid off this error?

Comment: Yes, install AArch64 Tensorflow like it says in both linked duplicates, instead of making MacOS emulate x86-64.